# String to Object Collection

Tags: c#

I Have this String

```
([{"id":"111","name":"Robocop","cover":"3114188e.jpg"},{"id":"222","name":"Eater","cover":"72dpi.jpg"}])
```

And is there better way to convert to Object Collection, couse now my crappy code looks like this:

```
var trimer = myString.TrimStart('(', '[').TrimEnd(')', ']');
string[] coll = trimer.Split('{','}');

string content = "";
foreach(string i in coll)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(i) && i != "," && i != "")
    {
        content += i + "\r\n";
    }
}
string[] contentData = content.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (int i = 0; i < contentData.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string book = contentData[i].Replace(',','\t').Replace("\"","");
    string[] info = book.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string id = info[0];
    string name = info[1];
    string cover = info[2];
}
```

Comment: It's JSON. Try searching "C# parse JSON".

Comment: JSON indeed, though you have to remove the opening and closing parentheses `()`.

Comment: Correct Json Indeed, just use a NewtonSoft Json to deserialize the content into an object that a mapping for each and every entry in the string above

Comment: In case you can plan to use something like WebAPI for request / response, then you have to do nothing, it internally serialize the objects to Json for Response and vice versa for Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You actually have a JSON string. You'll need to remove the parenthesis (if they actually exist in the received string) and then you can deserialize it properly. This example uses [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
public void DeserializeFoo()
{
    var json = "[{\"id\":\"111\",\"name\":\"Robocop\",\"cover\":\"3114188e.jpg\"},
                 {\"id\":\"222\",\"name\":\"Eater\",\"cover\":\"72dpi.jpg\"}]";

    var foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(json);
    foreach (var foo in foos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", foo.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", foo.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Cover: {0}", foo.Cover);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("cover")]
    public string Cover { get; set; }
}
```